Gauss sum over imaginary quadratic field
Define the Gauss sum
$$ G\left( \frac{a}{m}\right) = \sum_{n(\text{mod}\ m)} e\left( \frac{a n^2}{m}\right) ,$$
then I know the following result:

For any $a,m$ with $(2a,m) = 1$,
$$ G\left( \frac{a}{m}\right) =  \left( \frac{a}{m}\right) \varepsilon_m \sqrt m ,$$
where
\begin{equation*}
\varepsilon_m  = \left\{
\begin{aligned}
& 1 ,  m\equiv 1(\text{mod}\ 4) \\
& i ,  m\equiv -1(\text{mod}\ 4).
\end{aligned}
\right. 
\end{equation*}

My question is:  Let $F = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$ with class number $h_F = 1$ and the ring of integer $\mathfrak{O}$, and
$$ G\left( \frac{a}{m}\right) = \sum_{n\in \mathfrak{O}/m} e\left( \mathrm{Tr} \frac{a n^2}{m}\right) .$$
Are there similar conclusions? Is there any literature where this result can be directly found? Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks!

See for example A quick proof of reciprocity for Hecke Gauss sums by Boylan and Skoruppa (JNT 2013), both for its basic handling of these sorts of sums and for references to earlier work. Per this article, Hecke wrote about these generalized Gauss sums in his book Vorlesungen über die Theorie der algebraischen Zahlen (1970). I did not look at this book to learn anything about it.
More broadly, these sums appear sometimes as "Hecke Gauss sums" or "Gauss sums over number fields". The moral of their story is that you can prove the same sorts of things about them.

Thank you very much!
